# How to configure elasticsearch cluster data node

Tags: elasticsearch, cluster-computing

I want to configure a elasticsearch DB cluster where all nodes are data node, but I want each node to put data only on self node. I dont want to configure replica shards. 
The purpose of this exercise is not to have a HA, but to see a cluster view of data in all nodes and when a node goes down it is ok for me if that node's data is not available in the cluster view.

Comment: So each node should contain the exact same set of data?

Comment: not exactly. Each node need to have its own data set. But when we see the cluster view each nodes data will participate in the view.